# rust diesel-cli setting up multiple env files for different environments

Tags: rust, database-migration, development-environment, production-environment, rust-diesel

I am new to rust programming. I am trying to learn how disel-cli works. It's quite similar to  knex in express node projects.

I have created two migartion files using following commands -

```
echo DATABASE_URL=postgres://username:password@<dev url>/diesel_demo > .env.dev

echo DATABASE_URL=postgres://username:password@<prod url>/diesel_demo > .env.prod
```

I want to run migration to one of these two regions (**dev**/**prod**) by passing environment varibale. How do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the argument `--database-url` to specify the database you want the command on.

For example:
`diesel --database-url $(cat .env.prod) migration run`